# can't appear the list of my data using SQLITE

Tags: android

I am  beginner in android development and hope to find a solution to my problem.

I would like to see the list of items located in my database SQLITE when I add an article in my database SQLITE.

**PS:**

posting articles is done with a grid list
I need your help guys , I just want to see the list of articles that are in my database.
Here is the source code of GridListArt.java which is to display items in a list grid normally

ps: I done all what you asked me to and sorry to told you that I  can't see the items of my database

```
public class GridListArt extends Activity {
DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
static public GridView grid;
TextView txtTest;
Spinner spinDept1;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.gridviewart);
    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridart);
    txtTest=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtart);
    spinDept1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinart);

    UtilitiesArt.ManageDeptSpinner(this.getParent(),spinDept1);


    Button btnOne =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaddart);
    btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddArticle.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    final DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try
    {

     spinDept1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LoadGrid();
            //sca.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        txtTest.setText(ex.toString());
    }



    try
    {
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SQLiteCursor cr=(SQLiteCursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            try
            {
        // remplir les txtbox avec les valeurs qui convienne dans la base de donnée

            String name=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colArtCode));

            String Dept=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colSFamName));
            Article emp=new Article(name , db.GetSFamID(Dept));
            emp.setIdArt((int)id);
            AlertDialog diag= AlertsArticle.ShowEditDialog(GridListArt.this,emp);
            diag.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    txtTest.setText("dismissed");
                    //((SimpleCursorAdapter)grid.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    LoadGrid();
                }
            });
            diag.show();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                AlertsArticle.CatchError(GridListArt.this, ex.toString());
            }finally {
                cr.close();
        }

        }
    }
    );
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    //LoadGrid();
}

public void LoadGrid()
{
    dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try
    {
        //Cursor c=dbHelper.getAllEmployees();
        View v=spinDept1.getSelectedView();
        TextView txt=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtDeptName);
        String Dept=String.valueOf(txt.getText());
        Cursor c=dbHelper.getArtBySFamid(Dept);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String [] from=new String []{DatabaseHelper.colArtCode, DatabaseHelper.colSFamName};
        int [] to=new int [] {R.id.colcodeart,R.id.colsfamname};
        SimpleCursorAdapter sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.gridrowart,c,from,to);
        grid.setAdapter(sca);



    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder b=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        b.setMessage(ex.toString());
        b.show();
    }
}
```

}

my log cat  :

08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/mina.android.DatabaseDemo/databases/demoDB' 
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:2063)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1117)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1074)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:927)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at mina.android.DatabaseDemo.DatabaseHelper.getFamilleCount(Unknown Source)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at mina.android.DatabaseDemo.AddFamille.onStart(Unknown Source)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1137)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4607)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1943)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 18:02:28.452: E/System(17926): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2221)
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2313)
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2309)
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2274)
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1246)
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:2034)
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:185)
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
08-22 18:02:28.462: E/System(17926):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/mina.android.DatabaseDemo/databases/demoDB' 
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:2063)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1117)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1074)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:927)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at mina.android.DatabaseDemo.DatabaseHelper.getArticlesCount(Unknown Source)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at mina.android.DatabaseDemo.AddArticle.btnAddEmp_Click(Unknown Source)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3121)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3660)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14427)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/SQLiteDatabase(17926):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 18:02:28.512: E/System(17926): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2221)
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2313)
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2309)
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2274)
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1246)
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:2034)
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:185)
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
08-22 18:02:28.522: E/System(17926):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: `c.close();` -> don't close it. otherwise the adapter can't read stuff.

Comment: I edited my code source thanx for your answer :)

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/android-sqlite-database/).

Comment: thanks for your helps  , I know how to show dataand I did it in another table with the same methode  but I don't know why I can't see the data of this table

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I understand that you wanna read your database.

If it's true, my solution is get the .db file which store your data and read it using SQL Lite browser.

Comment: yes ! when the dataBase is empty it show nothing but when I add articles it appear an exeption WHICH told me that I should close my cursor and I don't know who to fix that :/

Comment: SORRY but I don't understand you

Comment: haha, you confused me with your previous answer. So, the problem is the exception?

Comment: SORRY , yes that's my probleme when I add new article I can't see my items because the exception appear when I add a new article

Comment: if so, please attach your exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you need to close your cursor.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
SQLiteCursor cr=(SQLiteCursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            try
            {
            // remplir les txtbox avec les valeurs qui convienne dans la base de donnée

            String name=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colArtCode));

            String Dept=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colSFamName));
            Article emp=new Article(name , db.GetSFamID(Dept));
            emp.setIdArt((int)id);
            AlertDialog diag= AlertsArticle.ShowEditDialog(GridListArt.this,emp);
            diag.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    txtTest.setText("dismissed");
                    //((SimpleCursorAdapter)grid.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    LoadGrid();
                }
            });
            diag.show();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                AlertsArticle.CatchError(GridListArt.this, ex.toString());
            } finally {
                cr.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's done but nothing has change thanks for your answer

Comment: what do you mean by "done"? Is that solved the problem? If not, what's the exception?

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem , I can't see my items and it doesn't appear any exception in the log cat :/

Comment: are you sure that your db contained those data which you want to get?

Comment: aaah yes because when I insert it increments  the nombre of articles